# Given $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a\geq b\geq c>0$

Tags: inequality

Given $a,b,c\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $a\geq b\geq c>0$, prove the following inequality. $$\frac{a^2-b^2}c+\frac{c^2-b^2}a+\frac{a^2-c^2}b\geq3a-4b+c$$I don't know how to deal with the asymmetric form of the inequality. I tried to group similar term (positive/negative sign, same numerator term, and same denominator term) and apply the term into some inequalities such as $QM\geq AM\geq GM\geq HM$. I ended up stuck and couldn't find the answer.

Step-by-step solution or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LHS is equal to $\frac{(a-b)(a+c)(b+c)(a+b-c)}{abc}$.  Letting $a-b=x$ and $b-c=y$, the inequality is equivalent to
$$x(x+y+2c)(y+2c)(x+2y+c)\geq c(x+y+c)(y+c)(3x-y).$$
However,
$$(x+y+2c)(y+2c)-4c(y+c)=xy+2cx+y^2\geq 0.$$
So $(x+y+2c)(y+2c)\geq 4c(y+c)\geq 3c(y+c)$.  Hence
\begin{align}x(x+y+2c)(y+2c)(x+2y+c)&=x(x+2y+c)(x+y+2c)(y+2c)\\&\geq x(x+y+c)(x+y+2c)(y+2c)\\&\geq x(x+y+c)3c(y+c)
\\&=c(x+y+c)(y+c)(3x)
\\&\geq c(x+y+c)(y+c)(3x-y).\end{align}
The equality holds iff $x=y=0$, which means $a=b=c$.

In fact, we have a stronger inequality:
$$\frac{a^2-b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2-b^2}{a}+\frac{a^2-c^2}{b}\geq 4(a-b),$$
with equality iff $a=b$.  Here is a yet stronger inequality:
$$\frac{a^2-b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2-b^2}{a}+\frac{a^2-c^2}{b} \geq 4(a-b)+\frac{(a-b)(b-c)(a+c)(b+c)}{abc},$$
where the equality case is still $a=b$.

Comment: What is the best way to know how to factor them in the first place ?

Comment: I simply plugged in $a=b$ to see what happens on LHS.  Since it became $0$, I would then know that $a-b$ is a factor.  After dividing by $a-b$, the numerator of LHS is a quadratic polynomial in $a$, which is easy to factorize.

Answer (score 3):

$$a \ge  b \ge c >0 \implies \frac{a+b}{c}]\ge 2, \frac{b+c}{a} \le 2, \frac{c+a}{b} \ge 1.$$
Then as $(a-b)\ge 0$, we can write
$$\frac{a+b}{c} \ge 2 \implies \frac{(a-b)(a+b)}{c} \ge 2(a-b) \implies \frac{a^2-b^2}{c}\ge 2(a-b) ~~~~(1)$$
Next as $(c-b)\le 0$, we have
$$\frac{b+c}{a} \le 2 \implies \frac{(c-b)(c+b)}{a} \ge 2(c-b) \implies \frac{c^2-b^2}{a} \ge 2(c-b)~~~~(2)$$
Again as $(a-c) \ge 0$, we have
$$\frac{a+c}{b} \ge 1 \implies \frac{(a-c)(a+c)}{b} \ge (a-c) \implies \frac{a^2-c^2}{b} \ge  (a-c)~~~(3)$$
ADDINg (1), (2), (3) we prove that
$$\frac{a^2-b^2}{c}+\frac{c^2-b^2}{a}+\frac{a^2-c^2}{b} \ge  3a-4b+c$$

Comment: Yes., you are right I have changed them all over.